# Transistor capacitor circuit . need help

Tags: transistors, capacitor

This isn't working as expected. It should work like this:
the led should stay on after pressing push button for one second.
Although when I press push button once then led stays on for 4-5 minutes and very slowly fades away.

Why isn't this circuit working properly?

[image: The circuit]

Comment: a CAP WILL REVERSE CHARGE IF YOU REVERSE CHARGE IT. bUT BADLY AND USUALLY IN A POORLY DEFINED WAY ||Whoops - CapsLOcK :-) |  Return -v e side of C1 to ground. If necessary place a high value R across it to control discharge. Not ideal but probably better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This circuit is reminiscent of a boot strap. When Q1 is off the space between Q1 and R5 is at ground level. When you press the button you charge C1 (reversed polarity!). Once C1 is charged it will supply current to Q2 that will intern supply current to Q1. When Q1 begins to conduct the spot between Q1 and R5 begins climbing in voltage pushing the base of Q2 higher. This action further turn on Q2 and then Q1. Finally when the charge that was stored in C1 is depleted the circuit will slowly dim the led until it turns off. The time the circuit stays on depends on the effective resistance of the base emitter junctions of Q1 plus Q2 plus R3 and the size of C1.

Comment: how can a electrolytic capacitor be reverse charged

Comment: @Sahota - your circuit will apply a reverse voltage to the capacitor because it is a bad circuit.

Comment: An electrolytic capacitor is polarized. This means that voltage should only be applied to it in the marked fashion. If voltage is applied in reverse of the markings, the capacitor has a chance of failing or even exploding.

Comment: what would happen if i reverse the polarity of capacitor

Comment: That would be an improvement but as @Sahota stated the circuit is badly designed. Watch this http://www.eevblog.com/2012/03/30/eevblog-262-worlds-simplest-soft-latching-power-switch-circuit/

Answer (score 0):

Your circuit is not working properly because it is not designed correctly. You haven't really given enough information, but based on what you have; I am thinking you want something similar to one of the circuit on this page [Link](http://www.mosaic-industries.com/embedded-systems/microcontroller-projects/electronic-circuits/push-button-switch-turn-on/latching-toggle-power-switch).

There are several there, if you are just interested in driving the LED then the two NAND Gate circuit (the first one) would be fine. If you are going to plan to have this circuit be the power for a microcontroller then you can investigate some of the other ones that can deliver more power.

Answer (score 0):

1) The polarity of the capacitor is backwards.

2) You need a discharge resistor for the capacitor.  Place a high-value resistor across the capacitor.  Adjust the resistor value for the desired delay time.

3) Check the value of R3 to make sure that it is the value shown in your schematic.

4) As others have already said: this is a poor circuit design.

When the button is released, the only discharge path for the capacitor is from the base current of Q2.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest that you consider a Silicon Controlled Rectifier (SCR) for this application.  Remove C1, R3, R4, and both 2n2222s.  Connect the upper end of R1 to the gate of the SCR.  The Anode and Cathode of the SCR would go between Rs 2 and 5.

Comment: A SCR is not suitable for this application because there is not a mechanism for turning the SCR off after it has latched on.

Comment: just add a second switch - had this circuit worked, you'd have needed one as well to either discharge the cap or cut overall power